# Errors downloading Powerpoint and PDF files after nginx update

Tags: pdf, nginx, download, gzip, powerpoint

I am hosting my site on an nginx server at DigitalOcean & ran some updates.
Before the updates, I was able to upload PDF and Powerpoint files to the server and download them without problems.

Now, whenever I try to download a file I recieve an error "Powerpoint found a problem with content in FILENAME.pptx...." and the attempted repairs are unsuccessful. The same holds true for most (but not all) PDF files ("Failed to load PDF document").

The errors occur in files that contain images and I was wondering if it has something to do with gzip. Turning gzip off completely did not change anything.

Any ideas what might cause these errors?

Here are parts of my nginx.conf file:

```
http {
    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##
    client_max_body_size 10M;

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;
    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    #gzip_vary on;
    #gzip_proxied any;
    #gzip_comp_level 6;
    #gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    #gzip_http_version 1.1;
    #gzip_types text/plain text/css applicat
    #gzip_types text/plain;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake: The update had changed the user in the nginx.conf file to "user  = www-data". After changing it to my original user name everything works again as expected.

Answer (score 0):

it would be useful to have a piece of the log files. Rather difficult to give you a response without them.

Have you tried to do a WGET or a CURL?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Here is the nginx/error.log $ sudo tail -n 5 /var/log/nginx/error.log
    2015/05/29 01:03:26 [alert] 3761#0: aborting
    2015/05/29 10:10:27 [notice] 6237#0: signal process started
    2015/05/29 10:24:03 [notice] 6491#0: signal process started
    2015/05/29 12:17:25 [notice] 2265#0: signal process started
    2015/05/29 12:46:11 [notice] 2589#0: signal process started                     It works fine to download files up to 100kb (powerpoint/pdf with and without pictures) anything large, and the downloaded files are reduced in size (often 63kb) and corrupted.